# Why there is many delay in update of uiview?

Tags: ios, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have three view controllers.
First VC name is VC1(initial view controller) that has label and a container view inside it.
Second VC(VC2) is a PageViewController that embedded inside container view of VC1.
The thirth VC(VC3) is content page of VC2.

---

```
class VC1: UIViewController, DelegateClass1{

    func setText(_ index: Int) {
        lblIndex.text = "\(index)"
    }  

...

}
```

---

```
protocol DelegateClass1: class {
    func setText(_ index:Int)
}


class VC2: UIPageViewController,UIPageViewControllerDelegate,UIPageViewControllerDataSource, DelegateClass2 {

    func setTextFromVC3(_ index: Int) {
        delegateClass1?.setText(index)
    }

var delegateClass1:DelegateClass1?

...
}
```

---

```
protocol DelegateClass2: class {
    func setTextFromVC3(_ index:Int)
}


class VC3: UIViewController {

var delegateClass2: DelegatClass2?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {    
    delegateClass2?.setTextFromVC3(pageIndex)
}

...
}
```

The problem:

After I change the current page of VC2 by scroll, I want index of new page show inside label of VC1, So I put this command inside didAppear Event of VC3. I tested it many times on simulator and it get many seconds to update label text. I don't use any asynchrous method. Where is the problem?
Thanks.

---

**Edit:**
A new discovery in my problem: I see when I use Page Curl instead of Scroll as Transition style of VC2, delay problem doesn't exist, but I don't want this transition style.

Comment: have you tried to do it in `viewWillAppear(_:)`?

Comment: @Rico -  I tried your comment and it worked when I scroll a page completely. But If I did an incomplete scroll, Although viewWillAppear called again with the page before scrolling, but label text changed with delay as before. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` to update your label? Make your `VC1` conform to the `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`, and set the delegate before before you embed your page view controller instance inside the `VC1` container. And then override this method:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
        didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished
   previousViewControllers:(NSArray<UIViewController *> *)previousViewControllers
       transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {
        if (finished) {
            lblIndex.text = "\(index)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this way and although it has few differences with my approach (In my approach I made VC2 conforms to UIPageViewControllerDelegate and UIPageViewControllerDataSource) but the result was same as before.

Comment: Well, then I can't think of anything else that might cause the delay. Try dispatching the delegate call to the main thread and see if that helps. `DispatchQueue.main.async { delegateClass2?.setTextFromVC3(pageIndex) }`

Comment: No, same as before.